# string and number comarison in javascript on lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```
let v = {"Reason__c": {
            "controllerValues": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 2,
                "1/2": 0
            }
        }};
buildPickLists(val) {
  console.log('val-------', val); //val------- 1/2
  console.log('typeof val-------', typeof val); //typeof val------- string
  let key = v.Reason__c.controllerValues[val];
  console.log('key-------', key); //key------- undefined
}
```

key is coming back as undefined as it is comparing .5 to "1/2". I've tried to convert it so the comparison works but have not figured it out thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val.Reason__c.controllerValues[k]` should have been `v.Reason__c.controllerValues[val]`. Two mistakes in a row (plus a stray `)`) means you were simply getting the wrong property from the wrong object. When programming, you should avoid similar variables (e.g. v/val/k/key). This is almost certainly the problem.

```
let v = {"Reason__c": {
            "controllerValues": {
                "1": 1,
                "2": 2,
                "1/2": 0
            }
}
};
buildPickLists(val) {
  console.log('val-------', val); //val------- 1/2
  console.log('typeof val-------', typeof val); //typeof val------- string
  let key = v.Reason__c.controllerValues[val];
  console.log('key-------', key); //key------- 0
}
```

Comment: thanks. I was fixing as you wrote this. Just a typo - still an issue

Comment: @SkipVV This corrected versions works in its context (I actually tested this in my browser). If val is a string, and val is "1/2", then it should find the correct value from the object. This means that you've likely got another variable that's the problem. Without more of the original code, it's hard to go much beyond that.

Comment: My apologies, poor execution of a post/question on my part, Made it confusing. The above is correct and I still have the issue

Comment: called like this after onchange - 
buildPickLists(event.target.value);

Comment: if val is 1 or 2 it returns the correct value for key

Comment: the val returns 0 instead of undefined now. I don't know what I did. I don't think I changed anything. I'm still having an issue but it's further down the road for which I'll open a new question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SkipVV It's okay, we've all had "mystery programming moments." If you can't figure it out every once in a while, don't worry about it.